# Why do I need to change project compliance to 1.5?

Tags: java, maven-2

I created a project with maven2 on eclipse. After I added the hibernate-annotations dependency, i was trying to create a class using hibernate annotations(@Entity, @Table...), but it was giving me this error :

> Change project compliance and JRE to 1.5

I fixed it, but cannot understand why it requires this as long as my jdk is 1.6.

Thank in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check that the settings for the maven compiler plugin is set to 1.5 or 1.6 as well. If I'm not mistaken maven 2 defaults to 1.4.

Something like this:

```
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.5</source>
                    <target>1.5</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Answer (score 9):

While [javamonkey79's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4049647/java-sais-to-change-project-complience-to-1-5-why-that/4049671#4049671) is the standard way to do it, there is also a property-based solution, but it's not [the one fgysin suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4049647/java-sais-to-change-project-complience-to-1-5-why-that/4049741#4049741):

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

Reference (Maven compiler plugin):

- [`<source>` parameter](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#source)
- [`<target>` parameter](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#target)

BTW, the reason is  that the [maven compiler plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin) builds a command line call to javac in which it specifies source and target version explicitly (overriding javac's default settings). And previous versions of the compiler plugin had their own defaults set to 1.3. However, starting from plugin version 2.3, [1.5 is the default source and target version](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MCOMPILER-80).

Comment: Setting the compiler level is becoming one of the memes of SO ;) (+1)

Answer (score -2):

Add the following lines to the POM:

```
   <properties>
      <java.version>1.6</java.version>
   </properties>
```

Edit:
Ah, too bad, just saw that those are custom properties... Won't work.

Comment: Whaaaaat? Where does this comes from? And what is this supposed to do?