# mvn clean install ignores source and target version

Tags: maven-2

I'm getting the error: annotations are not supported in version 1.3 when I do a mvn clean instal.
However in my pom.xml I have

```
<build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.5</source>
                        <target>1.5</target>
                    </configuration>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>x.y</groupId>
                            <artifactId>z</artifactId>
                            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
```

So it seems to be ignoring my source and target version for some reason.
Does anyone have any idea why this is occuring?

Comment: There must be 10⁹ dupes of this question, at least :)

Comment: @Pascal just mark it as a dupe then

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4049647/why-do-i-need-to-change-project-compliance-to-1-5, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2239959/setting-the-compiler-versions, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012582/maven-default-compiler-compliance-level, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531650/default-maven-compiler-setting, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531260/how-can-i-force-maven-to-package-my-project-against-1-5, etc, etc, etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most probably the `compile` goal is failing.

The missing piece of config you need is this:

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <source>1.5</source>
    <target>1.5</target>
  </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

Comment: indeed the compiler plugin is responsible for compiling, the war plugin for making the war