# Eclipse: Why do I need to change project compliance to 1.5, even though my jre is 1.8

Tags: java, eclipse

In my eclipse i am using below line in a program:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> hm = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
```

It is giving me below error message:

> Change project compliance and jre to '1.5'

.

But i am using jre1.8, then why i am getting this error message.
Please help to resolve this.

Comment: Right click project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> select JRE System Library click Edit and select JDK or JRE after then click Java Compiler and select Compiler compliance level to 1.8

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4049647/why-do-i-need-to-change-project-compliance-to-1-5?rq=1 (but maven so..)

Comment: Generics were added in 1.5. The message may be requesting *at least* Java 1.5.

Comment: Make sure your compiler level and language level match. The 1.8 compiler may well be set up in your project settings to compile to 1.5 bytecode.